# Number of rows of each sub-cell in a cell array

Tags: matlab

I have a cell `C` in Matlab of dimension `mx1`, e.g. `m=3`

```
C={{1 2 3; 4 5 6} {4 5 6} {7 8 9 10; 11 12 13 14; 15 16 17 18}}
```

Is there a way to get the vector `D` of dimension `mx1` reporting the number of rows of each sub-cell in `C` without using loops? In the example  `D=[2 1 3]'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is identical to your last (now deleted) question, just use `size` instead of `length`:

```
D = cellfun(@(x)(size(x,1)), C)
```

But note that `cellfun` is just a wrapper for a for-loop so doing this does not avoid loops.

Note a better solution (from Luis Mendo's comment) is

```
[D, ~] = cellfun(@size, C)
```

This way you can get the number of rows and the number of columns in one shot:

```
[nr, nc] = cellfun(@size, c)
```

Comment: Also `[D, ~] = cellfun(@size, C)`

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this two instructions :

```
cellsz = cellfun(@size,C,'uni',false);
cellsz{:}
```

you will get something like :

```
ans =
   4     2
ans =
  3    1
ans =
   5    3
```